# How do I change the color around the list area?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

In SwiftUI how would I go about changing the background color around the list?  I've tried using various `ZStack` and `.listRowBackground(Color.clear)` but no luck.  Here's some sample code.

[image]

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color(.blue)
            VStack {
                List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "clock")
                        Text("Placeholder")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093021/12299030?

Comment: Well maybe I'm missing something, but `listRowBackground` just changes the list background color, not the area surrounding the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. With [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), which changes this *specific* `List` (my recommendation)
2. Change the styling of all `List`s globally (I would not recommend as this could affect many different components)

Result of these solutions:

[image: Result]

#### 1: Introspect

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "clock")

                Text("Placeholder")
            }
        }
        .introspectTableView { tableView in
            tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

#### 2: Global appearance

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "clock")

                Text("Placeholder")
            }
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

---

You can also so the following instead to ignore the safe area for the background color:

```
.background(Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea())
```

Comment: Thank you!  There doesn't seem to be a native way to do this outside of option #2 it seems.

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately not. However I do highly recommend the Introspect method, plus it's a package I use very often to solve even basic problems like this. Introspect is like the better way than using `UIViewRepresentable`s and stuff.